# How to convert a SkyCoord catalog to an array of ra and dec pairs

Tags: astropy, astronomy

I have matched two catalogs, and now have the matched ra and dec values. They are shown with skycoord. I want to get a list of just all the ra and dec values.

I have tried to use np.array() and .to_string()

```py
max_sep = 1.0 * units.arcsec
idx, d2d, d3d = cat_ch1.match_to_catalog_3d(cat_ch2)
sep_constraint = d2d < max_sep
c_matches = cat_ch1[sep_constraint]
catalog_ch2_matches = cat_ch2[idx[sep_constraint]]

radec_ch2 = catalog_ch2_matches.to_string()
```

I want to get an array similar to if i just took the ra values and then the dec values and then combined them to get an array where each element is (ra, dec).

Comment: It would be helpful to post a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Set up a SkyCoord with some data:

```
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord

c = SkyCoord(ra=[10, 11, 12, 13]*u.degree, dec=[41, -5, 42, 0]*u.degree)

print(c)
```

Output:

```
<SkyCoord (ICRS): (ra, dec) in deg
    [(10., 41.), (11., -5.), (12., 42.), (13.,  0.)]>
```

Make and list of list with ra/dec paids in decimal degrees

```
sky_coords = []
for i in range(len(c)):
    sky_coords.append([c[i].ra.degree,c[i].dec.degree])
print(sky_coords)
```

Output:

```
[[10.0, 41.0], [11.0, -5.0], [12.0, 42.0], [13.0, 0.0]]
```

Make and list of list with ra/dec paids in hours and radians (and rounding to 5 places):

```
sky_coords = []
for i in range(len(c)):
    sky_coords.append([round(c[i].ra.hour,5),round(c[i].dec.radian,5)])
print(sky_coords)
```

Output:

```
[[0.66667, 0.71558], [0.73333, -0.08727], [0.8, 0.73304], [0.86667, 0.0]]
```

There's much more on how to use SkyCoord in astropy here: https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/

Comment: Attempting to follow this solution gives the following error: `AttributeError: 'SkyCoord' object has no attribute 'ra'`